# Where is the Courant operad discussed?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, qa.quantum-algebra, operads

Where is the Courant operad discussed? And hopefully defined precisely.

By the Courant operad or rather a suitable generalization of operad to accommodate the inner product,  the operad whose algebras are Courant algebras is meant.

Comment: What is the Courant operad? (even if unprecisely)

Comment: Ironically, currently the top two Google results for "Courant operad" are this page here and [this other page](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/courant-algebroids).

Comment: Knowing a little bit the works of the author of the question, does this have something to do with [http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Courant+algebroid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Courant+algebroid) ?

Comment: Yes to Philippe's query  By the Courant operad or rather a suitable generalization of operad to accommodate the inner product, I meant the operad whose algebras are Courant algebras.

Comment: Dear @Jim Stasheff, perhaps you could edit the question to include the content of your comment and clarify what you are asking.